# Grouping in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have these data inside my database :

[image]

And I'm trying to select those data to be displayed in a form with a specific group like this :

[image]

At first I am thinking of fetching all data and display with a `while loop`, but doing that will make the form to display repeated data from column `hp_lessons`. How do I query it to get the exact data like the expected output in the 2nd picture by using only one query?

Comment: You don’t want to GROUP your data in the MySQL query at all - since you still want all six records. You want to ORDER them by the lesson first ... and then you implement a simple _control break_ in your scripting logic that displays the data from the query result.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM <table-name-here> blah, blah, blah`.

Comment: SQL is not intended to do table formatting. You do that with the application connected to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the function `GROUP_CONCAT()` in MySQL. Here your request would be :

```
SELECT hp_lessons, GROUP_CONCAT(hp_timeslot SEPARATOR ',') as dates
FROM myTable
GROUP BY hp_lessons
```

This would give you a column 'dates' in your result, containing a string of all the concerned dates separated by a comma. You would just have to explode it in PHP to have an array. It sure is not the best method, and your database structure is not optimal regarding what you want to achieve, but this will do the work eventually.

Comment: Thank you. That helped me a lot :)